# 'Pollution affects the environment in many ways' - What part of the speech is 'in many ways'?

Tags: sentence, parts-of-speech

> Pollution (S) affects (V) the environment (O) in many ways (?).

Is *in many ways* a complement?

Comment: 'in many ways' does not have a part of speech. Perhaps you're confusing categories and functions. (S), (V) * (O) are common syntax functions, note * (V) here is a function not a category i.e. the predicate (it can be argued it is both and *they are used as both*). Categories (POS) are 'verbs' adjectives, adverbs, determiners, pronouns etc. Functions can be adverbial clauses, prepositional phrases, complements, content clauses etc. Categories tend to be single-words-only, while functions are not restricted to a single word and can be phrases etc.

Comment: [...] Note, some grammars like CaGEL would denote a name such as "Mary" as functionally a NP (a clause function), but its POS would be a noun. Personally a phrase for me has to have more than a single word, but I have to accommodate a big grammar such as CaGEL.

Comment: As a part of that sentence, *in many ways* is not a complement. If you need a term, you could call it an adverbial adjunct or an adverbial modifier. It's a prepositional phrase that functions as an adverb to answer the question of *how* for the verb: affects how? affects in many ways.

Comment: It's a prepositional phrase, functioning as an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a complement clause, but an adjunct clause:

> Pollution (S) affects (V) the environment (O) | in many ways (?)

*In many ways*, is not a complement clause because they can be removed from the sentence and still remain grammatical:

> (S) + (V) + (O) + (adjunct clause)

Complement clauses are selected by a verb and act as arguments which are necessary for the sentence to remain grammatical. Therefore, complement clauses are often described as a type of ***subordinate clause***. If you want to read more about complement clauses, I have posted an answer to it [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523255/wasnt-vs-werent/523382#523382). I will be using the same grammar reference by Maggie Tallerman.

> ## Understanding Syntax by Maggie Tallerman, pg. 92-93
>
> Some embedded clauses ***are not selected by any verb, and instead are just optional
>   modifiers*** rather than arguments:
>
> > (34) 
> >     a. Mel will be there [when she’s good and ready]. 
> >     b. [If you’re leaving early], please get up quietly. 
> >     c. [Kim having left early], we drank her beer
>
> The clauses shown in brackets are all **`ADJUNCTS`**, to use a term introduced in Chapter 2; this means that ***they are not obligatory***. You can see this for yourself by removing them from (34); ***all the remaining sentences are fully grammatical***. In traditional grammar, these optional subordinate clauses are known as **`ADVERBIAL CLAUSES`**. They add a very wide range of additional meanings, including information about time, location and manner, purpose, and reason or cause. The if-clause in (34b) is known
>   as a **`CONDITIONAL`** clause.
>
> Here are some further English examples of adjunct clauses:
>
> > (35) 
> >     a. Mel will come to work [aftter she gets paid]. 
> >     b. [Because it was before dawn], we got up quietly. 
> >     c. We walked up the hill [(in order) to see the castle]. 
> >     d. We walked up the hill [for Lee to see the castle]. 
> >     e. We walked up the hill [so (that) Lee could see the castle]. 
> >     f. [While shutting the window], I accidentally knocked over the flowers.
>
> There are a number of points to note here. In English, and widely in other languages,
>   adjunct clauses have just the same sorts of properties as complement clauses. They
>   are often introduced by a complementizer. They may be finite or non-finite. Non-finite adjunct clauses sometimes have an overt subject (*for Lee to see the castle*) and sometimes only an understood subject (*in order to see the castle; while shutting the
>   window*).

But the main difference between complement clauses and adjunct clauses has been highlighted since the first paragraph and will be in ***italicised bold***.